# Find the locus of $w=1/z$ when $z$ lies on $y=2x+1$

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, transformation

For the transformation $w=\frac{1}{z}$, find the locus of $w$ when $z$ lies on the line with equation $y=2x+1$

I'm not quite sure how or where to start on this question. I know for instance that the locus of $z$ such that

$$|z-2| = |z+2-2i|$$

is the line $y=2x+1$. I'm not sure where I could go from here though

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If $z = t+i(2t+1)$ then
$$
  \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{t+i(2t+1)} = \frac{t-i(2t+1)}{5t^2+4t+1}.
$$
So your locus is parametrized by
$$
  (u,v) = \left(\frac{t}{5t^2+4t+1},\frac{-2t-1}{5t^2+4t+1}\right)
$$
where $w = u+iv$.
Let's try to find an equation for the image of this parametrization. It looks like
$$
  u^2+v^2 = \frac{t^2+(-2t-1)^2}{(5t^2+4t+1)^2} = \frac{1}{5t^2+4t+1},
$$
and
$$
  2u+v = \frac{-1}{5t^2+4t+1}.
$$
So every point in the image of the parametrization satisfies
$$
  u^2+v^2+2u+v=0.
$$
This can be rewritten as $(u+1)^2+(v+\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{5}{4}$, a circle of radius $\sqrt{5}/2$.

The image of the parametrization isn't the whole circle; it's the whole circle minus one point. I will leave it to you to figure out which point is missing and why. (The point will be filled in if we let $t = \infty$, speaking informally.) (Which might be a bit of a hint for finding which point is missing, I guess.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is it the centre of the circle that's missing! This seems a little difficult to do without some software assistance!

I eventually got to the same answer by subbing in z=1/w into the $|z-2|=|z+2-2i|$. But I needed to use mathematica to do some of the simplifying!

Thanks very much for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $z=x+iy$ then as $y=2x+1$ we have  $w=\dfrac{1}{x +(2x+1)i}$

$\dfrac{1}{x +(2x+1)i}=\dfrac{x-(2x+1)i}{5 x^2+4 x+1}$

If $w=a+bi$ then we have $(a,b)=\left(\dfrac{x}{5 x^2+4 x+1},\dfrac{-2 x-1}{5 x^2+4 x+1}\right)$

So

$a=\dfrac{x}{5 x^2+4 x+1};\;b=\dfrac{-2 x-1}{5 x^2+4 x+1}$

$x=\dfrac{1-4a\pm\sqrt{-4 a^2-8 a+1}}{10 a}$

plugged in $b$ gives

$b=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(-1\pm\sqrt{1-4 a (a+2)}\right)$

$2b=-1\pm\sqrt{1-4 a (a+2)};\to (2b+1)^2=1-4 a (a+2)$

$a^2 + b^2+2a-b=0$

which is the equation of a circle. When $z$ varies on the blue line, $w$ varies on the orange circle

Hope it helps

*remark*

There are two points which are invariant

$\left(-\dfrac{4}{5}, -\dfrac{3}{5}\right),( 0,1)$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. One of the others just beat you to it but thanks very much for this

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,z = x + i(2x + 1)=(1+2i)x + i \,\mid\, x \in \mathbb{R}\,$, then $\bar z = (1-2i)x - i\,$. Eliminating $\,x\,$ between the two gives the equation in complex numbers for the line $\,z\,$ lies on:

$$
(2+i)\,z \,+\, (2-i)\,\bar z + 2 \,=\, 0
$$

Dividing by $\,2z \bar z\,$ and substituting $\displaystyle\,\frac{1}{z}=w\,$:

$$
(1-i/2)\,w \,+\, (1+i/2)\,\bar w \,+\, w \,\bar w \color{red}{+(1+i/2)(1-i/2)-(1+i/2)(1-i/2)}\,=\, 0 \\[5px]
\iff \quad (w+1+i/2)\,(\bar w + 1 - i/2) \,=\, |1+i/2|^2 \\[5px]
\iff\quad \left|w+1+\frac{i}{2}\right|^2 = \frac{5}{4}
$$

The latter is the equation of a circle of radius $\displaystyle\,\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\,$ centered at $\displaystyle\,-1-\frac{i}{2}\,$.